# How can I find out who added a user into a group with Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to get a list of members in a group. I can get a list of members with them names, links, etc.

How can I get the name of the user that added a user to that group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik this is not possible. Even the FQL table does not show any connection to the inviter:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member/

Comment: mmmmmmm :( , can I get it by any way ? I have a group with a big number of member , and I want to create a file contain each member add by whom ...

Comment: i doubt that you can get this info somehow. facebook (luckily) does not even allow adding users to group through the api, so you cannot even store them at the moment they were added...

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, that cannot be done.

[API Reference for groups](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) lists only the following properties for members: `id`, `name`, `admin`. If such information was available, I would expect it to be here as some additional property like `added_by`, which - sadly - doesn't exist.

Note that there is also an additional restriction: you can only list first 500 members for any given group. Thus, even if such attribute would exist, you couldn't access it for all members in large groups.

My only clue for this info is that when a user gets added into a group, they receive a notification about this event. This notification should contain the information about who added you to a group. However you cannot access user's private notification meaning this information is out of your reach.

As it seems you cannot access this info, I suggest you to think outside the box: what is the problem you are trying to solve by finding out who added who? For instance: if you really need this information, could I somehow collect this information directly from the users? Or for instance if you are doing some data analysis, would it be okay to let's say just assume for simplicity that users have been added by administrators unless proven otherwise?

Comment: you can add another properties from the left side in explorer : about , address , gender , etc ...

Comment: but I don't found the user that add a member to the group :(

Comment: my group contain less than 500 members

Comment: Please take time to read the whole answer through. Unless somebody figures out some really crazy hack, you cannot access that information, regardless of member count.

Comment: No problems! Final hint: try considering the wider view to the problem. Ask your self: why do I need to access information about who added who? What is the problem behind this and are there any other ways I could use to solve the problem?